# MongoDB: Adding data results in values with two (double) quotation marks for strings

Tags: string, mongodb, quotation-marks

I added some documents/data points in the MongoDB service that I am running on local (Windows).

The added data from csv includes strings but shows with double quotation marks around the values.

For example: `""Hello""`

I tried to aggregate using `$match` by `"var": "/"Hello"/"` but it didnt do anything.

sample:

```
_id:5e8b89a6e8b8fd408cd3c485
"":""1""
"date":""2007-01-01""
"code":""ABCD""
"price":""28391""
"t_id":""SE""
```

Some questions:

First, how do I insert data from csv without the double quotation marks

Second, even if I did insert them with double quotation marks, how do I use them effectively?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a sample data from the CSV file (a row will do). You can import CSV data into a MongoDB collection using the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html) command-line utility.

Answer (score 1):

got it to work using `\`:

```
"\"var\"": "\"Hello\""
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it - I don't see any forward slash in that string

Comment: comment is understandable but if you read the OP's problem and my solution then you would have gotten it. It is edited now